# amp in xml getting comverted to "&amp;"

Tags: php, xml, url, tinyxml

I am creating one url and adding & to that url.

```
eg http://xyzc.com/abc.php?arg1=value1&arg2=value2
```

Now I am adding this url to xml .

I am creating xml via tinyxml in c++ and also tried creating same xml in php.

After creating the xml I found out  that "`&`" is converted to "`&amp;`"

Is it okay for "`&`" to get converted to "`&amp;`"? Why is this happening ? And what could be the possible fix for this?

```
$strUrl ="http://xyzc.com/abc.php?";
$strUrl .="arg1=".$value1;
$strUrl .="&arg2=".$value2;
```

The output is coming as

```
http://xyzc.com/abc.php?arg1=10&amp;arg2=100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML has a feature called a character reference (`&thingy;`)

Therefore, all raw `&` characters must be escaped as `&amp;`
This is a pre-defined character reference equivalent to `&` (`amp` stands for ampersand).

Leaving an unescaped `&` will create invalid XML.

Note that raw `<` characters must also be escaped as `&lt;`  (`lt` stands for less-than).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_references

Comment: I tried using "&amp;" instead of "&" but now I am getting "&amp;amp" in XML

Comment: @Alien: Your XML engine escapes the characters automatically.  You should use `&`, and it will correctly generate `&amp;`.  In other words, your existing code is completely correct.